# Show different image for each row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, icons, abstracttablemodel

I'm building an application to manage a store's product for my project. I'm facing a problem and I really need your idea to solve it.

I successfully show image in product basic info table at the main screen using DefaultTableCellRenderer. But I can only show 1 image for all product. Each product has a different image, so I need to display different image for each row in the product basic info JTable.

Here is some pieces of my work.

This is my DefaultTableCellRenderer extended class:

```
class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
 JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("./src/comicbookandgamingzone/productpicture/NFS-Shift-2-Unleashed-Limited-Edition-Revealed-2.jpg");
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
  boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
lbl.setText((String) value);
lbl.setIcon(icon);
lbl.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
return lbl;
 }
}
```

The custom product basic info table model

```
class ProductTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
String[] colname = {"ID","Picture","Name","Cost","In stock"};
ArrayList<Product> list;
public ProductTableModel(ArrayList<Product> prolist){
    this.list=prolist;
}
public String getColumnName(int col){
    return colname[col];
}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    return colname.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    switch(columnIndex){
        case 0: return list.get(rowIndex).ID;
        case 1: return list.get(rowIndex).Picture;
        case 2: return list.get(rowIndex).Name;
        case 3: return list.get(rowIndex).Cost;
        case 4: return list.get(rowIndex).Stock;
        default : return null;
    }
```

...and in the show result method

```
public void ShowResult(ArrayList<Product> list){
    tabProduct.setModel(new ProductTableModel(list));
    tabProduct.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
    tabProduct.setRowHeight(100);
}
```

This is my SQL create table script. I store the path of the product image in database

```
create table ProductDetails
(
ProductID int identity (1,1) not null,
ProductTypeID int foreign key references ProductType(TypeID),
ProductName text,
ProductPicture text,
ProductCost float,
ProductPoint int,
ProductStock int,
primary key (ProductID)
)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: you are setting always the same image :S

Comment: Don't use stBounds, it has no effect as it it's up to the table to determine where the renderer should be position and at what size

Comment: Do you have something that ties `product` and its `image` together?

Comment: What links the product to the actual picture? Where are the pictures stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a custom renderer. JTable already supports a renderer to display an Icon. So all you need to do is:

1. store the Icon in the model for each row, the same way that you store the other text for each row.
2. Override the getColumnClass() method of the model to tell the table to use the Icon renderer. Something like:

   ```
   public Class getColumnClass(int column)
   {
       for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
       {
           Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

           if (o != null)
               return o.getClass();
       }

       return Object.class;
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you give me more details, please? I still can't build your idea in my mind

Comment: Details about what? What don't you understand?

Comment: I'm still working on how can I tell the table to use the rendering like you said. This is quite new with me, you know.

Comment: I told you what method to override and gave you the code to add to your model.